Drawing Matplotlib in PyQt / PySide6
I have imported matplotlib into my script:
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

I have created a class like this:
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=3, height=4, dpi=75):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width*3, height*0.8), dpi=dpi, facecolor='#1e1b18', linewidth=2)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_facecolor('#1e1b18')
        self.axes.tick_params(colors='#80c342')
        self.axes.spines['left'].set_color('#80c342')
        self.axes.spines['bottom'].set_color('#80c342')
        self.axes.spines['right'].set_color('#1e1b18')
        self.axes.spines['top'].set_color('#1e1b18')
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)

I have created a widget for PySide6 Layout:
    bottomFrameLayoutRight.addWidget(self.userGraphTextLabel, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.plotGraph = MplCanvas()
    bottomFrameLayoutRight.addWidget(self.plotGraph)

The final plot / draw order:
if len(widget.viewerCountPerMinute) == 5:
    widget.plotGraph.axes.plot(widget.userRunning, widget.viewerCountPerMinute, color='orange')
    widget.plotGraph.draw()

widget.userRunning and widget.viewerCountPerMinute are arrays, on which every 3 seconds a new element is appended. At the same time the first elements of this arrays are being deleted.
Example:
widget.userRunning = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
widget.viewerCountPerMinute = [17, 19, 23, 53, 42]

3 seconds later:
widget.userRunning = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
widget.viewerCountPerMinute = [19, 23, 53, 42, 523]

I want that the actual arrays are being plotted.
.plot() gives me a one time plot, which is not being updated.
.draw() draws the correct graph, but it is getting longer and longer because it draws the new points to the old graph.
I know, under normal circumstances, it wouldn't be worth to ask a question on this side, but in this case, it is a little bit special because of the PySide thing.
